# Iterate through Umbraco nodes and group into two's using Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco

I'm trying to iterate through my Umbraco node tree, using Razor, and I'd like to organise the results into groups of two within a simple HTML list but I can't think of a solution.

For example, here's my Umbraco node tree in it's simplest form:

```
- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 3
- Node 4
- Node 5
- Node 6
- Node 7
- Node 8
```

And I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Node 1</span>
        <span>Node 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Node 3</span>
        <span>Node 4</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Node 5</span>
        <span>Node 6</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Node 7</span>
        <span>Node 8</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [undocumented](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet/issues-suggestions/30615-Missing-inGroupsOf%28%29) `InGroupsOf` method, you can accomplish this fairly easily:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var group in Model.Children.InGroupsOf(2))
    {
        <li>
        @foreach (var node in group)
        {
            <span>@node.Name</span> 
        }
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

More `InGroupsOf` examples:

- [Grouping in Razor (Umbraco 4.7.1)](https://gist.github.com/nul800sebastiaan/1067257)
- [How to group nodes of data in Umbraco Razor](http://www.simonantony.net/knowledge-base/articles/grouping-nodes-in-umbraco-razor/)
- [IngroupsOf](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/33050-IngroupsOf)